# C++ passing strings causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I am attempting to do a simple demographics input->output program. Enter persons information and it writes it to a csv file.  However I can not get the name portion to work.  I always get a segmentation fault.  The code below is the offending bits and will not work. I know it has something to do with the strings, if I change to int it works just fine.  All other data input(which has been remove for simplicity)works.

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "People.h"
using namespace std;
void demographics();

int main()
{
    demographics();
    return 0;
}

void demographics()
{
    short elements = 2;
    Names test[elements];
    vector<string> name2;
     for(int i =0; i<=elements; i++)
    {
        string name;
        cout << "Please enter first name for child " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> name;
        name2.push_back(name);
        test[i].setName(name2);
    }
    return;
}
```

People.h

```
#ifndef PEOPLE_H_INCLUDED
#define PEOPLE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Names
{

    private:
        vector<string> names;
    public:
        void setName(vector<string>&);
};
```

People.cpp

```
#include "People.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Names::setName(vector<string>& f_l_name)
{
    names = f_l_name;
}
```

Comment: Thats a total of 3 elements which is what I am looking for. I want to enter the information for 3 people.  Why would that cause the error? To clarify I did change to just < and it worked

Comment: `Names test[2];` creates an array with two elements, not three. You use `test[1]` after that to get the 2nd element, because indexing starts at 0... Initialization is not indexing.

Answer (score 7):

`for(int i =0; i<=elements; i++)`

Should be

`for(int i =0; i < elements; i++)`

Comment: Are you saying the for loop should not end?   It should just read for(int i=0; i) ?

Comment: @user3547452: pdm is saying you're reading one too many elements.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, when it was first posted it just said for(int 1=0; i